# Add and Subtract Time

Tags: php, datetime

I have always had a problem with adding and subtracting time like for an 
example:

```
   10h:34min 
 + 07h:46min
 -----------
    XX:XX
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767068/adding-30-minutes-to-time-formatted-as-hi-in-php

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382458/subtracting-a-certain-number-of-hours-days-months-or-years-from-date

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370332/add-two-or-more-time-strings-in-php

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456886/adding-time-in-php

Comment: Whoa, wait, this site has a search function?

Comment: Also, you might want to specifcy the XX:XX part. What is the addition supposed to return when the hour exceeds 23? Should it keep counting hours or add 1d to the output? What if subtracting would yield a negative number?

Answer (score 1):

Convert your time(s) to minutes, add them and re-calculate hours and minutes:

time in minutes ("tim"): (10 * 60 + 34) + (7 * 60 + 46)
result: floor(tim/60) : (tim%60)

floor(tim/60) will give you the whole hours
tim%60 is the "modulo" which is the integer "rest" of (tim/60)

If you work with whole dates (and times, not durations like it seems you do), try mktime and/ or strtotime which support operations like "+10 minutes" (and other).