# Adding time to existing time with PHP

Tags: php, time

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding time in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456886/adding-time-in-php)

I would like to add time to 9:00 AM using php. I can not get it to convert properly. Here is what I am using:

```
date("g:i A",mktime("9:00 AM +1 hours"));
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Sorry I meant date("g:i A",strtotime("9:00 AM +1 hours"));

Comment: @champton then edit the question please. not that it would be less of a dup

Answer (score 1):

You need to be using [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

```
date("g:i A",strtotime("9:00 AM +1 hours"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `DateTime` object, you can add time like this:

```
$dt->add(new DateInterval('PT1H'));
```